# Logistic Regression performing better than SVM with a Gaussian kernel performing better than a linear SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, logistic-regression

I am very new to machine learning.

I am working with a data set, and my algorithm for logistic regression (with lasso regularization) is performing fairly well (~0.8 AUC), my SVM with a Gaussian kernel is doing well (~0.7-0.8 AUC), and my SVM without a kernel is doing fine but not as well (~0.7 AUC). It seems odd to me that a SVM with a kernel would have a performance in between two algorithms which do well with linearly separable data. Is this normal, and what could be going on here? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Could it be because of Lasso's hard thresholding?

In response to Jason's query, my dataset has roughly 800 features and 800 observations, and is all numerical.

Comment: Can you describe your dataset in detail? How many observations and variables? Normally SVM performs well but computation time is super long. I can explain in detail if you give a little bit of information about your dataset.

Comment: Thanks whoever moved this to the comment section :)

Comment: Are these test scores? Are the train scores in the same order?

Comment: These are test scores, yes. I think the SVM train scores were slightly higher than the logistic regression train scores, but insignificantly so (all high 0.9s).